# TinyMCE Editor change underline button behavior - u tag instead of span text-decoration underline

Tags: tinymce, wp-editor, plugin-tinymce

As above. I want to change the WordPress Edtior TinyMCE behavior when I click the underline button I want the TinyMCE to wrap my selection with `<u></u>` tags. Now, I know that the u tag was deprecated in HTML 4~ but according to W3 it can be used in HTML5 again. Anyways! I need a `<u>` tag - not a `<span>`.

Is there a way to change the default underline button behavior without any shortcodes or editing core files? Something like a hook to change the editor behavior in `functions.php` would be nice :) Thanks!

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16878373/577418) and answers.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solutions doesn't work. Tried turning the inline function into standalone one but still nothing, wraps with span.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After few days I got it to work. Gotta check those core files, now I know how. Anyways, here is the working code:

```
function my_tiny_mce_tweaks( $first_init ) {
  $first_init['formats'] = '{' .
      'alignleft: [' .
          '{selector: "p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li", styles: {textAlign:"left"}},' .
          '{selector: "img,table,dl.wp-caption", classes: "alignleft"}' .
      '],' .
      'aligncenter: [' .
          '{selector: "p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li", styles: {textAlign:"center"}},' .
          '{selector: "img,table,dl.wp-caption", classes: "aligncenter"}' .
      '],' .
      'alignright: [' .
          '{selector: "p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li", styles: {textAlign:"right"}},' .
          '{selector: "img,table,dl.wp-caption", classes: "alignright"}' .
      '],' .
      'strikethrough: {inline: "del"},' .
      'underline: {inline: "u"}' .
  '}';

  return $first_init;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'my_tiny_mce_tweaks');
```

Just add it to functions.php and you good to go. It will be probably easier if you remove the dots `.` and join the string. Hope it helps!

Comment: +1 but I assume you could have just change the value of `$first_init['underline']` instead of redoing all values. it might cause problems if there are more then one plugin hooking on that filter

Comment: It probably won't work. With the code above I'm changing the array part and 'underline' is a part of the string in that array part. Would be better to just change the underline part but without ex. RegEx it's not possible.

Comment: Oh you are right

Comment: `json_decode()` to parse the JSON, edit the array, then `json_encode()` the result.

Comment: Great idea @AstDerek but I get NULL from decoding that string... Any ideas why? I think that because for ex. `alignleft` isn't wrapped with `"alignleft"` quotation marks. Might be wrong tho.

Comment: @pbe You are right. I thought that was just an example JSON object, but it is indeed an invalid JSON :(

Comment: That's a shame. No PHP functions to decode the above string, though? Thanks!

Comment: In Wordpress 5.6, this does not work for the align properties. I'm still getting inline styles instead of class names applied to my selectors.

Comment: And you're definitely using TinyMCE, not Gutenberg, as the editor?

Comment: (but this probably belonged as a comment on the other answer)

Comment: Gutenberg and the block editor do not use TinyMCE, you should ask a new question

Comment: Alternatively, you can manipulate `$first_init['formats']` to insert the additional `,underline: {inline: "u"}` just before the closing `}` like this: `$first_init[ 'formats' ] = substr( $first_init[ 'formats' ], 0, -1) . ',underline: {inline: "u"}}';`